# Real Analysis - Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((4n^2 + 7n)/(6-5n^2)) = -4/5$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} ((4n^2 + 7n)/(6-5n^2)) = -4/5$

so I started off by using the definition of convergence to show

$$\left|\frac{4n^2 + 7n}{6-5n^2} - \frac{-4}{5}\right| < ε$$

$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{4n^2 + 7n}{6-5n^2} - \frac{-4}{5}\right| &= \left|\frac{4n^2 + 7n}{6-5n^2} - \frac{4n^2-(24/5)}{6-5n^2}\right|\\ & = \left|\frac{7n - 24/5}{6-5n^2}\right|\end{aligned}$$

Now I don't know what to do here with the $6-5n^2$ in the denominator. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done.

The numerator is less than
a constant times $n$,
and the denominator is
greater than
another constant times
$n^2$.

Since
$\frac{n}{n^2}
\to 0$
as $n \to \infty$,
that gives you
what you want.

The fact that the denominator
is negative does not matter - 
only the absolute value matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to carry out another algebraic step to make it clearer that your final expression converges to zero as $n\to \infty$, you can check that
$$\left|\frac{7n-24/5}{5n^2 - 6}\right| \leq \left|\frac{7}{5n}\right|$$
whenever $n \geq 2$. Indeed, the above inequality holds if and only if
$$|35n^2 - 24n| < |35n^2 - 42|$$
as can be seen by cross-multiplying, and if $n\geq 2$ the absolute values can be removed since the expressions inside them are positive:
$$35n^2 - 24n < 35n^2 - 42$$
This is equivalent to
$$42 < 24n$$
which is satisfied for all $n \geq 2$.